# deserialize xml 2 pojo jackson

Tags: java, xpath, serialization, jackson, pojo

i want to deserialize xml to pojo dynamically using custom field mapper.
For example I have pojo:

```
class Person{
    String f1;
    String f2;
}

class Mapper {
    String getFieldXpath(String field) {
         if(field='f1')
             return "someXPathToFiled1";
         if(field='f2')
             return "someXPathToFiled2";

    }
}
<client>
     <age>23</age>
     <sex>neutral</sex>  
<client>
```

What I want is to map the xml to pojo, not statically map property to fields from xml using jackson annotations, but to use mapper, that for field f1 will map value from xpath returned by mapper

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify more details about what you want to do?

I should use JAXB and XJC like this:

https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/generate-your-jaxb-classes-in-second/

Comment: I read and xml. Then want  to populate pojo with values from the xml. When i use jackson anotation then it statically links some xml field name to pojo field. I want instead to use some class that will during pojo population provide the xpath to proper field in xml. So then i will not have to change annotation, but only my 'mapping' class